# Integration and sequence

Tags: integration

> Let $$\int_0^x f^2(t)\;dt=\left( \int_0^x 2f(x-t)\;dt \right)^2, \quad f(1)=1$$ function $f(x)$ is continuous for $x>0$, $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence such that $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sqrt{1+a_n^2}$ for $a_0=0$. If $f(x)$ is an increasing function, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_k}{2^{n-1}}$$ where $k=f(n^{\sqrt{2}-1})$ equals to $$(\text{A}) \frac{\pi}{4}\qquad (\text{B}) \frac{\pi}{8}\qquad (\text{C}) \frac{4}{\pi}\qquad (\text{D}) \frac{8}{\pi}$$

Please give some hint. How to approach to solve the question?
I tried differentiating the function on both sides by applying the **Newton-Leibniz  formula** but I was not able to solve further.

Comment: Consider posting how did you approach or what all have you tried, so that other users will be able to help you better.

Comment: Note that $k = f(n^{\sqrt{2} - 1})$ is not necessarily an integer… But, at least, you can figure out the unique function $f$ which satisfy the condition on the integrals. (tip: differential equation of the first order, differentiate and look for relations)

Comment: I tried to solve but not able to find any good relations among those functions.Please can you provide any other hint ?

Comment: @Raito plz give me some sort of strong hint. I found $f(x)$=$e^{8(x-1)}$ is that correct.plz Tell me how to find the sequence.

Comment: I think it is not correct. You can write the calculations to check them.